# Missing scrollbar in ScrollViewer containing ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want my `ItemsControl` to have an automatic vertical scrollbar when the content doesn't fit. I've added a `ScrollViewer` around it but it doesn't show the scrollbar and instead makes the items not wrap at all.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RecipientsNames}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="btnContact" Click="BtnContact_Click"
                    Width="Auto" Height="14" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0 0 6 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="12" Margin="0 -2 0 -2"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I've also tried binding ItemsControl's Width to the ScrollViewer's Width but it didn't work either (`Width="{Binding ElementName=MyScrollerName, Path=Width}"`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should already work, when you set HorizontalScrollbarVisibility="Disabled" instead of "Hidden"

Comment: Yep, this also works. Thanks!

Comment: This scrolls the ItemsControl  instead of the items in the ItemsControl. You should edit the template if you want to add a scroll bar to the ItemsControl itself.

Comment: Well, the final effect is the same. The user will not see the difference between scrolling the ItemsControl or the items inside of it.

Comment: They will if you for example specify a border for the ItemsControl.

Comment: Any particular reason why you decided not to upvote my answer?

Comment: I think my question implied that I didn't care much about where the scrollbar would be (on ItemsControl or inside of it). And I eventually went with Spongebrot's solution as it was shorter. But I tested yours too and it worked and you posted it as an answer and hence I marked it as *the* answer. You also want an upvote additionally?

Also, any ideas why my question is downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `ScrollViewer` around the `ItemsPresenter` in the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="btnContact" Click="BtnContact_Click"
                            Width="Auto" Height="14" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0 0 6 0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="12" Margin="0 -2 0 -2"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And get rid of the outer `ScrollViewer` element.